# Notation for kernel object

Tags: notation, category-theory

When $f: A \mapsto B$ is a morphism in some category with a zero object and limits, we can use $\ker(f)$ to refer to an equivalence class of morphisms to $A$ which satisfy a particular universal property. For a paper I'm writing, I need a clear and efficient way of referring to a kernel *object*, i.e. the domain of a kernel morphism. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Whenever I do something with a category that has kernel objects, i.e., equalizers of a map $f$ with the zero map, I write $\operatorname{Ker}f$ for the kernel object and $\operatorname{ker}f$ for the kernel map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Geoff suggests in the comments, you can use $\text{Ker}$ for the object and $\text{ker}$ for the morphism. But I don't think this convention is universal so you should probably say that you're using it. I sometimes use $\text{ker}$ for both.